# Convert GMT timezone to user specifc timezone

Tags: java, android, date, datetime, timezone

In my android application I have to parse a date of format `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz`. I am extracting the time from this using below method. this works perfect. but the time always displays in GMT format, so I have to convert it in to user time zone, for that I have added one more line in my code before parsing, the code is  `inputFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());`
since this is not working I have changed the argument in to `TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")`, `TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Kolkata")` and so on, but nothing works, the time still comes in GMT format.

what is the problem for this actually ? how can I resolve this, any help is appreciated

```
public static String extractTime(String dateInput) {
        Date date = null;
        String time;

        try {
            DateFormat inputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(mFormat, Locale.getDefault());
            date = inputFormatter.parse(dateInput);
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        SimpleDateFormat outputFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
        time = outputFormatter.format(date);
        return time;
    }
```

**Update**

I have tried setting timezone to outputFormatter instead of inputFormatter, but it is still same, no change in output.

**Example :**

Input : `Tue, 21 Jul 2015 09:02:30 GMT`

Output getting : `05:02:30`

Comment: You should set the timeZone to `outputFormatter` instead of `inputFormatter`.

Comment: @Codebender no change it is same

Comment: Can you put an input and it's expected output, and the output you are actually getting?

Comment: @Codebender please check question I have added the current input and output

Comment: Please put your expected output also. And the timezone. I tried setting timezone to outputformatter and I am receiving proper time based on the set timezone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things to note about dates and DateFormat. A date object in Java is always in UTC - the way how it is printed (even in things like `System.out.println()`) depends on the timeZone (e.g. in sysout the timeZone is the system's default TZ).

So, having said that let's come to your problem. You first want to parse a String that contains a date in a certain timeZone. Let's assume that datestring is in the user's TZ - to convert it to the correct UTC time you have to tell the DateFormat which TZ the String is in that it is parsing:

```
// Assuming you have the userTimeZone already
inputFormatter.setTimeZone(userTimeZone);
```

When you now parse the date you get the correct java.util.Date object. If you want to format this to get a String that only contains the hours, minutes and seconds you again have to define the desired target TZ. Assuming this is also the user's TZ:

```
outputFormatter.setTimeZone(userTimeZone);
```

When you now format the date with this formatter you will get the time String in the user's TZ.